# Remove values from drop down lists

Tags: jquery

Currently, I have two drop down lists that are populated with users' first and last names.  When a user is selected from the first drop down list, the name is unavailable in the second drop down list.

I would like to add a third drop down list that makes the values selected in the first and second lists unavailable.  How may I modify my current code to support this feature?

The current code may be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/NfTNA/

```
    function removeOptions(selectA,selectB,selectC) {
    var firstValue = $(selectA).children(":selected").attr("value");
    var secondValue = $(selectB).children(":selected").attr("value");
    var thirdValue = $(selectC).children(":selected").attr("value");
    // get the other element from the hidden select to put back
    var prior = $("#hiddenContainer").children("[value!="+secondValue+"]").data("prior");
    if (prior != undefined) {
        $("#hiddenContainer").children("[value!=" + secondValue + "]").insertAfter($(selectB).children("[value=" + prior.prior + "]"));
    }
    if (firstValue != 0) {
        // add the prior id data to the element before removing it
        var priorValue = $(selectB).children("[value="+firstValue+"]").prev().attr("value");
        $(selectB).children("[value="+firstValue+"]").data("prior",{prior:priorValue});

        // move the selected element of selectA in selectB to hidden select 
        $(selectB).children("[value="+firstValue+"]").appendTo("#hiddenContainer");
    }
    // reselect the option in the secondary select
    $(selectB).val(secondValue);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify - the first and second dropdowns have lists of names. When you chose a name from the first list, it is removed from the second list. What would happen to the third list?

Comment: The names selected in the first and second lists will not be available in the third list.

Comment: The other question I have that can be viewed as an addon to glosrob's question is - what happenes if the user picks the 3rd dropdown or the 2nd dropdown first? Or is the second dropdown only enabled when the user makes a selection on the first one?

Comment: Currently, the order in which the selection is made does not matter.  If userA is selected from the second drop down list, userA is not avilable in the first drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with jQuery (see http://jsfiddle.net/NfTNA/38/)

Example markup

```
<label for="reviewer">Select 1<sup>st</sup> Reviewer:</label>
<br />
<select name="optionsA" id="optionsA">
    <option value="">&ndash; select &ndash;</option>
    <option value="jsmith">Smith, John (jsmith)</option>
    <option value="bwright">Wright, Bob (bwright)</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="reviewer">Select 2<sup>nd</sup> Reviewer:</label>
<br/>
<select name="optionsB" id="optionsB">
    <option value="">&ndash; select &ndash;</option>
    <option value="jsmith">Smith, John (jsmith)</option>
    <option value="bwright">Wright, Bob (bwright)</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="reviewer">Select 3<sup>rd</sup> Reviewer:</label>
<br/>
<select name="optionsC" id="optionsC">
    <option value="">&ndash; select &ndash;</option>
    <option value="jsmith">Smith, John (jsmith)</option>
    <option value="bwright">Wright, Bob (bwright)</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
var firstSelected = null;
var secondSelected = null;

//initally order select lists (this is a bit of cheat, to help later on

$('#optionsA').change(function() {
    //remove the currently selected option from 2nd/3rd drop down
    var selectedValue = $('#optionsA option:selected')
    if (selectedValue.val() != "") {
        $('#optionsB option[value="' + selectedValue.val() + '"]').remove();
        $('#optionsC option[value="' + selectedValue.val() + '"]').remove();
    }
    else {
        selectedValue = null;
    }

    //add previous item back in to 2nd/3rd drop down
    if (firstSelected != null) {
        $('#optionsB').append($('<option>', { value : firstSelected.val() }).text(firstSelected.text())); 
        $('#optionsC').append($('<option>', { value : firstSelected.val() }).text(firstSelected.text())); 
    }

    //save the currently selected value
    firstSelected = selectedValue;
});

$('#optionsB').change(function() {
    //remove the currently selected option from 1st/3rd drop down
    var selectedValue = $('#optionsB option:selected')
    if (selectedValue.val() != "") {
        $('#optionsA option[value="' + selectedValue.val() + '"]').remove();
        $('#optionsC option[value="' + selectedValue.val() + '"]').remove();
    }
    else {
        selectedValue = null;
    }

    //add previous item back in to 1st/3rd drop down
    if (secondSelected != null) {
        $('#optionsA').append($('<option>', { value : secondSelected.val() }).text(secondSelected.text())); 
        $('#optionsC').append($('<option>', { value : firstSelected.val() }).text(firstSelected.text())); 
    }

    //save the currently selected value
    secondSelected = selectedValue;
});
```

This is based on the following:

- select an option from select list 1, removes option from select lists 2 and 3
- select an option from select list 2, removes option from select lists 1 and 3
- previously selected options are added back into lists

Comment: He might want that values back if the the values are changed in the second drop down list..

Comment: Correct, the current code works as desired, only needing to append it to allow for a third related drop down list.

Comment: In my defence, that is a pretty major requirement to miss out! Your jsFiddle only shows 2 dropdowns? How does that marry with your question?

Comment: In its current state, my code uses two drop down lists.  I am looking for help in adding a third list, hence its absence.  Your code above does exactly what I am looking for and it is more slim than my original code.  Thank you for your help and understanding!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YHjuz/1/
It will give you the idea to proceed further.
And FYI, you cannot hide option item of a Drop down list in IE7.

Comment: This is a fine example as well.  The accepted solution provides exactly what I wanted; however, I will keep your suggestion and advice in mind.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be oversimplifying, but I see you seem to be trying to keep the selected value and removing all others when changing the last dropdown, so how about just doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#optionsC').change(function() {
        $('#selectA').find('option:not(:selected)').remove();
        $('#selectB').find('option:not(:selected)').remove();
    });
});
```

Or if you are trying to remove the name in the 3rd box from box A and B:

```
$('#optionsC').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if (selectedValue != "") {
        $('#optionsA option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
        $('#optionsB option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
    }
});
```